# Typescript with Angular HttpClient ErrorType ... is not a function when calling class method

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, angular-httpclient, typescript-types

I'm facing some weird (to me) problem with objects and types in typescript/angular.

I have some class describing my objects received from remote API:

```
export class Point {
    lat:number;
    lng:number;
    name:string;

    public doSomething() {
        console.log("doSomething called");
    }
}
```

I'm using `HttpClient` to get objects from API:

```
constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

getPointsAsync(callback: (points: Point[]) => {}) {
    this.http.get<Point[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/points`)
    .subscribe(
        (result: Point[]) => {
            //do something with data
            callback(result);
        },
        error => { //some error handling
        }
    );
}
```

My problem is that when I try to call method `doSomething` on one of my Point from array

```
var firstPoint = points[0];
firstPoint.doSomething()
```

I get some weird error on console:

```
ERROR TypeError: firstPoint.doSomething is not a function
```

I'm not using Typescript and Angular for very long so I'm assuming that it is something wrong with my code but I couldn't find answer to my issue. Could you give me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.assign()` will solve your current problem, but not if you have nested objects.  Then you will have to do `Object.assign()` for each nested object as well, which can get tedious if you have to do this in multiple places in your codebase.

I suggest an alternative: [class-transformer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-transformer)  With this you can mark your nested fields with annotations that tell the compiler how to create the nested objects as well. With this you only need to use the `plainToClass()` method to map your top level object and all the underlying fields will also have the correct types/objects.

### Example

Let's say we have two classes:

```
class Parent {
    name: string;
    child: Child;

    public getText(): string {
        return 'parent text';
    }
}

class Child{
    name: string;

    public getText(): string {
        return 'child text';
    }
}
```

**The first case** we already know doesn't work:

```
let parentJson: any = {name: 'parent name', child: {name: 'child name'}};
let parent: Parent = parentJson; // note: compiler accepts this because parentJson is any.  
        // If we tried to assign the json structure directly to 'parent' it would fail because the compiler knows that the method getText() is missing!

console.log(parent.getText()); // throws the error that parent.getText() is not a function as expected
```

**Second case** using `Object.assign()`:

```
let parentJson: any = {name: 'parent name', child: {name: 'child name'}};
let parent: Parent = Object.assign(parentJson); 

console.log(parent.getText()); // this works
console.log(parent.child.getText()); // throws error that parent.child.getText() is not a function!
```

to make it work, we would have to do the following:

```
let parentJson: any = {name: 'parent name', child: {name: 'child name'}};
let parent: Parent = Object.assign(parentJson);
parent.child = Object.assign(parentJson.child);

console.log(parent.getText()); // this works
console.log(parent.child.getText()); // this works
```

**Third case** with class-transformer:

First modify the parent class so that the child mapping is defined:

```
class Parent {
    name: string;
    @Type(() => Child)
    child: Child;

    public getText(): string {
        return 'parent text';
    }
}
```

then you can map to the parent object:

```
let parentJson: any = {name: 'parent name', child: {name: 'child name'}};
let parent: Parent = plainToClass(Parent, parentJson);

console.log(parent.getText()); // this works
console.log(parent.child.getText()); // this works
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you don' actually get instances of `Point` from the web service. You get a JSON object that has the class fields, but not the methods. You can use instantiate the class and use `Object.assign` to assign the values from the object literal to each `Point` instance

```
getPointsAsync(callback: (points: Partial<Point>[]) => {}) {
    this.http.get<Point[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/points`)
        .subscribe(
            (result: Partial<Point>[]) => {
                let points = result.map(p=> Object.assign(new Point(), p));
                callback(points);
            },
            error => { //some error handling
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I have to call ```Object.assign``` in every request where I need instances of specific class? Or maybe is it possible to move it elsewhere e.g. ```HttpInterceptor```?

Comment: @user3626048 I am not aware of another way to do it, you would need to pass the constructor somehow (the type parameter is not enough as that get erased at runtime)